# python queue get size, use qsize() or len()?

Tags: python, size, queue

I've seen instances where `qsize()` and `len()` has been used to compute the size of the queue. What is the distinction between the two?

Comment: Related question: [python - Why is len() not implemented for Queues? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585367/why-is-len-not-implemented-for-queues)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For most containers, you'll want `len`, but `Queue.Queue` doesn't actually support `len`. This may be because it's old or because getting the length of a queue in a multithreaded environment isn't particularly useful. In any case, if you want the (approximate) size of a `Queue`, you want `qsize`.

Comment: len might tempt people to check for nonzero length before doing a get, assuming that the get won't block.

Comment: I am getting this crash on Mac while calling qsize

return self._maxsize - self._sem._semlock._get_value()
NotImplementedError

any help ?

Comment: why is it approximate? What if you need exact?

Answer (score 4):

`queue.qsize()` doesn't return the number of bytes in the queue. It returns the number of "things" placed in the queue.

If you put 5 byte-arrays of 100 bytes in the queue, the `qsize()` will be 5, not 500.