# Why is len() not implemented for Queues?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, language-design

The built-in function `len()` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) returns "*the length (the number of items) of an object*", but this is not implemented for `queue.Queue` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).
Instead, `queue.Queue` has a `qsize()` method which returns the approximate size of a queue, when it clearly has a length; you can specify the maximum length of a `Queue` in the constructor. The similar `collections.deque` does work with `len`.

What are the reasons for not using the common `len()` for `queue.Queue`? Or: What would be the problems if `qsize` were instead named `__len__` to enable the `len()` function?

Comment: Maybe because people expect `len` to return an accurate value, not an approximate one. And that it should be fast. To implement an accurate  `__len__` the Queue would have to be temporarily locked to prevent additions & removals, which would impact performance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`len()` isn't implemented for `queue.Queue` because it would be an "attractive nuisance":  something that only an expert should even consider using, but a "friendly name" would encourage non-experts to use it.

Unlike most sequence types (like `list` and `deque`), a `queue.Queue` is specifically *intended* to be used in multi-threaded contexts (and similarly for the `multiprocessing` module's queue type).  While the number of items in a `Queue` certainly has a definite value at any particular time, it's impossible for user code to find out what that value is:  between the time a call to `.qsize()` returns and your code can *look* at the returned value, any number of other threads (or processes, in the `multiprocessing` case) may have made any number of changes to the queue's contents.

So the only true thing that can be said about the value returned by `.qsize()` is that the `Queue` *had* that many values in it at *some* time in the past.  By the time you can use the returned value, it may have arbitrarily more (or fewer) values in it.

Of course that's not so if you're only running one thread - but then there's no need to pay for the implementation complexity of a `Queue` (use a `list` or a `deque` instead).

Comment: so why are `empty()` and `full()` implemented for a queue?

Comment: They wouldn't implement `empty()` and `full()` if I had written them ;-)  In the early days, the various optional `timeout=` arguments didn't exist, and `full()` and `empty()` were used in loops as _probabilistic_ gimmicks to make a decent guess at whether `.put()` or `.get()` were "likely to" succeed.  Code using them (like code using `qsize()`) is as often as not prone to timing bugs.

Comment: i not an expert, therefore a simple and least surprising `len()`  sounds better to me than overthought `qsize()`. Specifics and possible inaccurateness of `len` could be explained in the help message and this should be sufficient for a programmer.

Comment: I don't understand. The `len` function is overrideable: "*[The `len()` function will use the `__len__` method if present to query your object for its length.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15114062/1201863)*" Why not just alias `__len__` to `qsize`? Then you get the exact same properties. It's not as if `if o.qsize() > 0: o.get()` is any more or less reliable than `if len(o) > 0: o.get()`.